# Calculate 4 previous quarters from a date - pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using the below to get the previous quarter from 'new_date' and it works great. How do I calculate 4 quarters back?

```
(F.expr("date_add(date_trunc('quarter', cast(new_date as date)), -1)"))
```

Comment: do you just want the quarter ending date of 4 quarters back? e.g., for 31DEC2020, you need 31DEC2019?

Comment: Apologies I wasnt specific enough. I need all 4 quarters dates. i.e. for 30.06.2021 previous quarters are 31.03.2021, 31.12.2020 and 30.09.2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html#pyspark-sql-functions-transform).

You get the previous quarter's ending date using your approach (or any approach), and create an array using that date 4 times (using [`array_repeat`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_repeat.html#pyspark-sql-functions-array-repeat)). Then use `transform` with `add_months` to subtract 3, 6, 9 months and use `last_day` to get the quarter ending date.

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('q1_back', func.date_add(func.date_trunc('quarter', 'dt'), -1)). \
    withColumn('qtr_arr', 
               func.expr('transform(array_repeat(q1_back, 4), (x, i) -> last_day(add_months(x, i*-3)))')
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +----------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
# |dt        |q1_back   |qtr_arr                                         |
# +----------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
# |2018-12-31|2018-09-30|[2018-09-30, 2018-06-30, 2018-03-31, 2017-12-31]|
# |2019-12-31|2019-09-30|[2019-09-30, 2019-06-30, 2019-03-31, 2018-12-31]|
# |2018-12-31|2018-09-30|[2018-09-30, 2018-06-30, 2018-03-31, 2017-12-31]|
# |2018-11-10|2018-09-30|[2018-09-30, 2018-06-30, 2018-03-31, 2017-12-31]|
# +----------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
```

The binary function provided in [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html#pyspark-sql-functions-transform) can access the 0-based index which can be used to subtract 3, 6, 9 months from the first quarter `[0*-3, 1*-3, 2*-3, 3*-3]`.

Comment: Extremely heplful - thank you!